# Groovy named positional argument with default value

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have this code:

```
def myFunc(arg1, arg2="default arg2", arg3="default arg3") {
    println("arg1: ${arg1}")
    println("arg2: ${arg2}")
    println("arg3: ${arg3}")

}

myFunc(1, arg3="foo")
```

My desired output:

```
arg1: 1
arg2: default arg2
arg3: foo
```

Actual output:

```
arg1: 1
arg2: foo
arg3: default arg3
```

I want to override the last argument without changing the middle `arg2` which has a default value I need.
I cannot use classes.
What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in groovy, The right most optional parameter is dropped first and so on and so forth.

Better explanation:
https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-parameters-with-default.html

The implementor would need to pass in the default 2nd param when invoking this method.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, this does not work - groovy has no named arguments.
One thing people often *confuse* for named arguments, is the passing of
maps.  E.g. you can have the defaults be merged with the arguments and
come *close* to what you are after:

```
def myFunc(Map kwargs = [:]) {
    def args = [arg1: "a1", arg2: "a2", arg3: "a3"].tap{putAll(kwargs)}
    println([args.arg1, args.arg2, args.arg3])
}

myFunc(arg3: "new a3")
// => [a1, a2, new a3]
```

You can also check for the incoming keys beforehand, that they are in
the default to notify the consumer at least at runtime, that they are
sending unknown keys.